# Python standard module for emulating geometric points

Tags: python, geometry

Is there a standard class in Python to emulate a geometric point that includes coordinates and a value, including arithmetic operations between the coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want standard matrix arithmetic operations for your coordinates, try [numpy](https://numpy.org/)'s array type.